# Python pandas: Search from multiple columns that contained strings of another column and map it to the new column

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, mapping

I have a dataframe looks like this:

| Premise | Thoroughfare | Locality | PostalCode | Country | FullAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Yew Tree Lane | Holmbridge | HD9 2NR | N Ireland | Old Thorn, Yew Tree Lane, Holmbridge HD9 2NR, N Ireland |
| 3 | Cysgod Y Castell | Llandudno Junction | LL31 9LJ | Uk | 3 Cysgod Y Castell, Llandudno Junction LL31 9LJ |
| 1168 | Christchurch Road | Bournemouth | BH7 6DY | Wales UK | 1168 Christchurch Road, BH7 6DY Bournemouth |

And want to create another column or dataframe that looks like this

| FullAddress | FullAdressWithTag |
| --- | --- |
| Old Thorn, Yew Tree Lane, Holmbridge HD9 2NR, N Ireland | Old^Others Thorn^Others, Yew^Thoroughfare Tree^Thoroughfare Lane^Thoroughfare, Holmbridge^Locality HD9^PostalCode 2NR^PostalCode, N^Country Ireland^Country |
| 3 Cysgod Y Castell, Llandudno Junction LL31 9LJ | 3^Premise Cysgod^Thoroughfare Y^Thoroughfare Castell^Thoroughfare, Llandudno^Locality Junction^Locality LL31^PostalCode 9LJ^PostalCode |
| 1168 Christchurch Road, BH7 6DY Bournemouth | 1168^Premise Christchurch^Thoroughfare Road^Thoroughfare, BH7^PostalCode 6DY^PostalCode Bournemouth^Locality |

I am trying to map the ***FullAddressWithTag*** columns that based on data that is available on the single column such as Locality, Premise, PostalCode etc. Do note that the pattern of the FullAddress might be vary.

For example, it can be:

- Premise -> Thoroughfare -> Postalcode -> Locality
- Premise -> Thoroughfare -> Locality -> PostalCode
- Thoroughfare -> Premise -> Postalcode -> Locality

It can be in different position depends on how the FullAddress given. If the element in FullAddress doesnt have a tag, it will tags as "Others"

I have million records for this data to be map with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long and bulky code that could get your job done:

```
def getDFwithFullTag(df1):
    cols_to_check = ['Premise', 'Thoroughfare', 'Locality', 'PostalCode', 'Country']
    def checkAddr(row):
        ans = ''
        for st in row['FullAddress'].split(' '):
            flg = False
            for col in cols_to_check:
                if st in row[col].split(' '):
                    if st[-1]==',':
                        ans += st[:-1]+'^'+col+', '
                    else:
                        ans += st+'^'+col+' '
                    flg = True
                    break
            if not flg:
                if st[-1]==',':
                    ans += st[:-1]+'^'+col+', '
                else:
                    ans += st+'^'+col+' '
        return ans
    ftag = []
    for i in range(len(df1)):
        ftag.append(checkAddr(df1.loc[i]))

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=df1.FullAddress)
    df_new.insert(1, 'FullAdressWithTag', ftag, True)
    return df_new
```

Apart from being large and ugly, this function would take around 20-30 minutes to process 1 million rows. This function takes a dataframe as input and outputs a dataframe of your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, performance-wise, but maybe it helps:

If the dataframe has `NaN`s instead empty strings `""` do `df = df.fillna("")` first. Then:

```py
import re

tags = {word: tag for tag in df.columns[:5] for word in set(df[tag]) if word != ""}

def repl(match):
    tag = tags.get(match[0], "Others")
    return " ".join(f"{part}^{tag}" for part in match[0].split())

def tagging(row):
    pat = "|".join(sorted(row.iloc[:-1], key=len, reverse=True)) + r"|\w+"
    return re.sub(pat, repl, row.at["FullAddress"])

df["FullAdressWithTag"] = df.apply(tagging, axis=1)
```

- First make mapping `tags` of the items in the columns `Premise`, `Thoroughfare`, `Locality`, `PostalCode` and `Country` onto the column names, the tags.
- Then `.apply` the `tagging` function to the dataframe rows:

  - The function packs the items of the tag-columns into a search pattern (a disjunction, sorted by length in reverse, augmented with a part to catch items that are not present in the columns).
  - Then use the pattern to add the tags with the `repl` function, which uses the `tags` mapping to do that. If the there's no key present for the address part then the `.get` returns `Others` as tag.

Result for the small sample:

```
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    | FullAdressWithTag                                                   |
+====+=====================================================================+
|  0 | Old^Others Thorn^Others,                                            |
|    | Yew^Thoroughfare Tree^Thoroughfare Lane^Thoroughfare,               |
|    | Holmbridge^Locality HD9^PostalCode 2NR^PostalCode,                  |
|    | N^Country Ireland^Country                                           |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 3^Premise Cysgod^Thoroughfare Y^Thoroughfare Castell^Thoroughfare,  |
|    | Llandudno^Locality Junction^Locality LL31^PostalCode 9LJ^PostalCode |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  2 | 1168^Premise Christchurch^Thoroughfare Road^Thoroughfare,           |
|    | BH7^PostalCode 6DY^PostalCode Bournemouth^Locality                  |
+----+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```